# Sending multiple messages through a socket in c

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

So in this program I am trying to send the file content and file name from client to server in two steps. I tried using `memset()` to empty the buffer so as to use it for storing the filename, however then I realised that the filename is being passed into the buffer along with the content, so there is no point of `memset()`. So, I need to separate the two transmissions I was thinking of closing the buffer for first process and then opening it for the second transmission again, I am not sure how to proceed.

Here's my code:

**Server.c**

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int fd =0, confd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

   char buff[1025];
   int num;

   fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   printf("Socket created\n");

   memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
   memset(buff, '0', sizeof(buff));

   serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);

   bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

   listen(fd, 10);

   while(1){

       confd = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);

       FILE* fp = fopen( "create.txt", "wb");

       int b = recv(confd, buff, 1024, 0);

       if(fp!=NULL){

           while(b>0){

           fwrite(buff, 1, b, fp);
           b = recv(confd, buff, 1024, 0);
           }
       }

       else{
           printf("Error!");
       }

       printf("Got it :)\n");
       //printf("Buff before: %s\n", buff);

       memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));

       num = read(confd, buff, 1024);
       //printf("Buff after: %s\n", buff);

       if(num<0){
           printf("error reading the socket");}
       else{
           printf("File uploaded: %s\n", buff);
       }

       //close(confd);
       fclose(fp);
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

**Client.c**

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int i=0, k=0,num;
    char ip[50];
    char upfile[50];
    char dwfile[50];



    for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
        if(strcmp(argv[i], "-i")==0){
            strcpy(ip, argv[i+1]);
        }

        else if(strcmp(argv[i],"-u")==0){
            strcpy(upfile, argv[i+1]);
            k =2;
        }

        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "-d")==0){
            strcpy( dwfile, argv[i+1]);
            k=3;    }

       /*  else(argv[i] = "-l"){
       }*/

    }
    printf("%s %s %s", ip, upfile, dwfile);

    int sfd =0, n=0, c;
    char rbuff[1024];

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    memset(rbuff, '0', sizeof(rbuff));
    sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);

    c = connect(sfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    if(c==-1){
        perror("Connect");
        return 1;
    }

   if (k==2){
       printf("==========This is the upload function");
       FILE *fp = fopen(upfile, "rb");

       if(fp == NULL){
           fprintf(stderr, "oh no!");
           return 1;
       }

       char sendbuffer[100];

       int b = fread(sendbuffer, 1, sizeof(sendbuffer),fp);
       while(b>0){
           send(sfd, sendbuffer, b, 0);
           b = fread(sendbuffer, 1, sizeof(sendbuffer),fp);
       }

       num = write(sfd, upfile, strlen(upfile));
       fclose(fp);

       printf("Send filename: %s", upfile);
       printf("============End upload!");
   }

   return 0;

}
```

Can anyone help ?

**EDIT1:**

Sending the filename before sending the file contents seems to work, but however doing that is printing a long trail of zeroes. For example: `File uploaded: tt.txt000000000000000000000....`

Answer (score 3):

There are two common solutions: One is to use a separator, a special byte or sequence of bytes, that can't be in the message data and that marks the separator between the two messages. In the case of you sending a binary file it's not really feasible since there are really no safe sequences.

The other common method is to have a special fixed-sized header which contains the length of the data you send. Then you simply send this fixed-sized header first followed by the actual data.

---

In your case you could use both methods actually, but I really recommend you send the filename *first*, or it will be hard for the server to open the file and write the data.

You could send the filename *with* the terminating zero, thereby having the string terminator as a field separator between the fiilename and the file data.

*Or* you could send both the length of the filename *and* the file data, followed by the name and the data.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, be sure not to allow a full file name to be sent - you can't trust
the client, and you wouldn't want *any* client to create an arbitrary
file.